# Magento fall-back on theme

Tags: magento

I installed a theme on my Magento instance, which I'd like to further customize. I imagine that similar to Magento's fallback hierarchy where my theme can fall-back on default packages, I should be able to structure my directories in such a way that I can make changes to particular parts of my theme by maintaining a similar structure and relying on a fall-back.

So here's my question: How can I develop a child-theme of another theme, with the fall-back setup this way? Is this performed by structuring directories a certain way, or is this performed some other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Magento EE 1.14 or CE 1.9 than you can utilize the method described here to make a child-theme: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide
http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes

> Important: It's very important you have a theme.xml in the
>   app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/etc directory with
>   exactly the contents shown. Failure to configure theme.xml correctly
>   prevents Magento from loading your theme.

You must create your theme structure as noted and place a theme.xml file within it, containing the following code:

Magento CE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
  <parent>custom_package/custom_parent</parent>
</theme>
```

Magento EE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
  <parent>custom_package/custom_parent</parent>
</theme>
```

For versions EE v1.8+ or CE v1.4+, you should reference here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

Heirarchy is as follows:

1. app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/ && skin/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme

If not found, then

2. app/design/frontend/custom_package/default && skin/frontend/custom_package/default

If not found, then

3. app/design/frontend/base/default && skin/frontend/base/default

If not found, then

4. throw error

Based on this you could place your default theme at custom_package/default and your child-theme at custom_package/custom_theme, all files not found at custom_package/custom_theme would then fall-back to custom_package/default. Whatever is missing is sought at the next level of hierarchy.

Set your Package and Theme at Admin > System > Configuration > Design

Answer (score 1):

Magento's fallback scheme is pretty simple to work with. You can select the package, theme, and default theme by navigating in your magento admin to System > Configuration > Design

Magento starts loading templates / layouts from

```
app/design/frontend/{SELECTED_PACKAGE}/{SELECTED_THEME}
```

if it cant find the file its looking for in there, it will look in

```
app/design/frontend/{SELECTED_PACKAGE}/{SELECTED_THEME_DEFAULT}
```

and failing that it will look in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default
```

So my recommendation to you is install your theme as the default theme, and put your customizations into your selected theme folder. Of course this fallback scheme can be used in a lot of different ways depending on what your needs are, but I've always felt this is the simplest and handles most use cases.

```
app/design/frontend/downloadedTheme/default <- Put your stock files in here

app/design/frontend/downloadedTheme/myCustominzations <- Put your changes in here
```