# Where Do I Put a Template To Add Using {{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and so sorry for the noddy question.

I am trying to add php to a CMS page and the way to do this appears to be to put the php (including Mage calls) to a phtml template and then add it to the CMS page with
`{{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}`.

But, in all the examples that I can find saying that this is the way to do it none of them tell me where to put the phtml file so I can use the above.

So my question is; where do I put a template to call using
`{{block type="core/template" template="template.phtml"}}`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35749/where-do-i-put-a-template-to-add-using-block-type-core-template-template-te/35752

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow [Magento].

An easy way to make this call from a static block is, add this to your static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/template.phtml"}}
```

Place page.phtml at this path, with your custom code:

```
app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/template/page/template.phtml
```

If you are still having problems, due to [Magento's hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777090/magento-fall-back-on-theme/25777391#25777391), you can also place it here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template.phtml
```

Be sure to flush your cache

Comment: Thank you for your replay. While working through what you have advised (even though I was sure I had tried this) I have realised that the reason that it was not working was that I had not clicked 'Hide Editor' before I had typed it. What you have advised has worked so thank you. Sorry for being such a fool. :)